# How to step up my CPU's frequency?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, cpu, frequency

I installed xubuntu 12.10 in a Fujitsu Siemens laptop with Intel Pentium M processor 1.86Ghz.
I noticed that the processor's frequency that the "System information" mentions is only 800Mhz (step down frequency).
How can I step up the frequency up to the processor's maximum (1.86GHz)?

Comment: It would likely be stepped up automatically as needed.

Comment: I see. What i have seen is that it shows some "delay" and this made me think that something keeps the processor from speeding up.Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The default mode for CPU frequency in Ubuntu is Ondemand, with demand the speed goes up, however you can control that either with cpu-freq indicator or Jupiter power applet.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for your attention and will to help.
It turns out that all I needed to do is to install "cpufrequtils" from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the available CPU frequencies using the following command:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
```

and you can see the current CPU frequency using:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

So here is an idea, run the following command in one terminal to observe the current CPU frequencies:

```
watch -n 1 cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq
```

..and then run some CPU demanding applications and you should see the CPU frequencies ramp up and down as the load changes.